# change width of bootstrap accordion panel (collapsed element)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my code I have classic bootstrap accordion Accordion, I want to change width of expanded ul/li when   is clicked (decrease width), now there is a full width of h5, anyone can help?

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

                <div class="panel" >
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#divListCiagniki">
                        <h5>ciągniki</h5>
                    </a>
                    <div id="divListCiagniki" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="width:50%">

                            <ul class="panel-body" >
                                <li>example</li>
                                <li>example</li>
                                <li>example</li>
                            </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#divListMaszynyRolnicze">
                        <h5>maszyny rolnicze</h5>
                    </a>
                    <div id="divListMaszynyRolnicze" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li>example</li>
                                <li>example</li>
                                <li>example</li>
                                <li>example</li>
                                <li>example</li>
                                <li>example</li>
                                <li>example</li>
                                <li>example</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: could you please provide your code in jsfiddle? would be easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to decrease the width of the ul/li tags,
Use

```
<div id="divListCiagniki" class="panel-collapse collapse"  style="width:<Required width>; overflow:hidden;">
```

//overflow: hidden hides the text which exceeds your width.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use something like this:

```
li:active { 
    width: 80% !imporant;
}
```

remember to use `!important`to overwrite bootstrap style

Answer (score -1):

I mean to change the width of div id: divListCiagniki or divListMaszynyRolnicze but unhappy both tricks above doesnt work

Comment: This seems to be a comment, not an answer.